# Error in dyn.load("path/file_name.so") : unable to load shared object

Tags: r, dll, fortran

I have several compiled Fortran subroutines to be used in R. when I try to call this specific subroutine it produces the following error :

```
Error in dyn.load("path/file_name.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/complete_path/file_name.so':
  libgfortran.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Although other subroutines are loaded perfectly, here is the subroutine:

```
subroutine box_center(m,n,o,a,b,ps,box,filter)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: m,n,o
    integer :: x,y,t,mone,none,a,b
    double precision, intent(inout) :: ps(m,n,o),box(a,b)
    double precision, intent(out) :: filter(m,n,o)

    mone=m - 3
    none=n - 3
    do 20,t=1,time 
      do 10, x=4,mone
       do 5, y=4,none
        box = reshape((/ps(x-3,y-3,t)  ,ps(x-3,y-2,t),ps(x-3,y-1,t) &
                        , ps(x-3,y,t)  ,ps(x-3,y+1,t),ps(x-3,y+2,t) &
                , ps(x-3,y+3,t) & 
                                , ps(x-2,y-3,t),ps(x-2,y-2,t),ps(x-2,y-1,t) &
                        , ps(x-2,y,t)  ,ps(x-2,y+1,t),ps(x-2,y+2,t) &
                , ps(x-2,y+3,t) & 
                                , ps(x-1,y-3,t),ps(x-1,y-2,t),ps(x-1,y-1,t) &
                        , ps(x-1,y,t)  ,ps(x-1,y+1,t),ps(x-1,y+2,t) &
                , ps(x-1,y+3,t) & 
                    , ps(x,y-3,t),ps(x,y-2,t),ps(x,y-1,t) &
                        , ps(x,y,t)  ,ps(x,y+1,t),ps(x,y+2,t) &
                , ps(x,y+3,t) & 
                                , ps(x+1,y-3,t),ps(x+1,y-2,t),ps(x+1,y-1,t) &
                        , ps(x+1,y,t)  ,ps(x+1,y+1,t),ps(x+1,y+2,t) &
                , ps(x+1,y+3,t) & 
                                , ps(x+2,y-3,t),ps(x+2,y-2,t),ps(x+2,y-1,t) &
                        , ps(x+2,y,t)  ,ps(x+2,y+1,t),ps(x+2,y+2,t) &
                , ps(x+2,y+3,t) & 
                                , ps(x+3,y-3,t),ps(x+3,y-2,t),ps(x+3,y-1,t) &
                        , ps(x+3,y,t)  ,ps(x+3,y+1,t),ps(x+3,y+2,t) &
                , ps(x+3,y+3,t)/), (/a,b/))


           if(minval(box) .EQ. box(4,4)) then                       
                filter(x,y,t) = 1.00
              else
                filter(x,y,t) = 0.00
             end if 


5          end do 
10         end do   
20  end do  
    end subroutine box_center
```

All subroutines are compiled with the same procedure:

```
gfortran -c -ffree-form file_name.f 
R CMD SHLIB file_name.f
```

Another point to mention: this specific subroutine loads fine when I use my local machine, it produces the error on the HPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a beginner like me will find it useful instead of deleting the question.

Compiling Fortran subroutine on the remote machine is the solution not in the local machine.